# H2 database inside a Docker container

Tags: docker-compose, h2

I have a Java application that uses an H2 database. The application is working fine. Now I would like to create 2 containers in Docker. One for my H2 database and other for my application.

I want my application be connected to the H2 database (which is in the other container). So, the point is that when my Application starts, it is not able to connect to the H2 database on the other container. Below, you can find my docker-compose file with the 2 services I am trying to run.

```yaml
services:
  db:
    image: openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
    ports:
     - "8082:8082"
    volumes:
     - ${PATH_TO_DATA:-/home/user/data}/h2:/root/h2
    command: java -cp /root/h2/h2-2.2.224.jar org.h2.tools.Server  -tcpAllowOthers -webAllowOthers

  appservice:
    image: openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
    ports:
      - "8070:8070"
    volumes:
      - ${PATH_TO_APP:-/home/user/dev/app}/backend/rest/spring1/dt_app/target/app-1.2.3.jar:/app.jar
    entrypoint: "java -jar /app.jar"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: When you say "is not able", what does that mean? Do you get an error message? How do you configure the connection? Also: when only the appservice needs to access H2, then you don't need a `ports` declaration for H2: that's only necessary for access from *outside* of docker.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When the application is trying to connect to the H2 it returns the next message: "org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection". I am using the next jdbc string to get the connection : "
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/h2/gw;AUTO_SERVER=true;INIT=create domain if not exists jsonb as text"

Comment: It seems that the application cannot identify the container in which the H2 database is running. When I run everything outside of the containers everything works fine, the application can connect to the H2 database.

Comment: Another docker container/service will look like a different host from inside docker, so `localhost` is wrong. You should use `db` as the host name (the service name).

Comment: Many thanks, it worked great! I have change "localhost" by "db" and now, the application in one container can connect to the database on the other container.

Comment: Additional question. I am using a cookie saved by the main application (on the host server). This cookie contains the "user name" (when the user logs into the main application, the system stores the "user name" in a cookie). I would like the secondary application inside the container (service appservice) to be capable of reading this cookie. In other words, can a cookie be passed by the main application to a secondary one inside the container?

Comment: Who connects to the appservice? Is it the main service? Then it can just include any cookie information in its request. If it's the users browser, then things become more tricky.

Comment: Hi Generous Badger, the main system (which runs on the host) calls at some point  an application that is a viewer to show a list of objects belonging to the user logged in to the main system. To make the interaction between both applications simple, we are saving the "user-id" in a cookie when the user first logs into the main system. Later on, the user clicks on a button and calls the viewer application (which is inside the app service). The viewer application needs the "user-id" because it will use this to filter the objects that belong to the user.

Comment: The viewer application recover this information from the cookie. As I understood from your answer, it should not be a problem since the cookie is stored in the browser and we are using the same browser to interact with the applications (the main system in the Host and the viewer in the Container). Is it correct?